# Sitecore personalization without storing users in the Core database

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, sitecore-dms

In my master database, I am storing user accounts of the website users under a user node (content\public users..\user1), I do not want to store them in the core database as Sitecore users (anonymous users). With this approach can I use sitecore personalization features comes up wth Sitecore DMS?

More details:
Features: Multivariate tests, Campaigns, Targeted contents for the user, user profiling

Is it essential to have the users in the core database as sitecore users (asp net membership users) to use these features?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "personalization features". For example, many of the rule conditions used for conditional rendering are based on data stored in the Analytics database and tied to the visitor by a cookie. Users (the type stored in the membership tables of the Core DB) don't come in to it. Perhaps if you could elborate on what you are looking to achieve, a we could provide a clearer answer.

Comment: In case anyone is wondering about this with sitecore 7.5+: This got completly changed there

Answer (score 0):

It is not essential to have the users stored in the core database to use DMS features like MV Testing, Campaigns, Personalization or Personas. You may not be able to use UserProfile attributes in any of the Personalization Rules though...it really depends on how you have implemented your user profile. If you created your own membership provider this could work.

http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/sc61keywords/membership_providers_a4.pdf